# inserting a variable into the drilldown of an object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am sure this question has been asked before, just don't know the verbiage to find it in a search. Basically I have an object which has values in it and values in that and so on and one of those values will change depending on what is in the text box so I need to make it a variable but it freaks out when I do.

SO if you go to this page:
http://shawnwow.com/chineseCharacterHelpr/

Type "mao" in the text box then go into console and type "currentPinyin" you SHOULD get "mao" and then if you type:

```
$.wordDatabase.words.mao.choices;
```

You would get the Chinese characters as expected for "mao" but I need to have it grab whatever is in that text box so I replace mao with the variable currentPinyin by putting in:

```
$.wordDatabase.words.currentPinyin.choices;
```

I get a vague error... even though I don't get errors when I manually use mao and currentPinyin is equal to mao. I am guessing it has to do with using a variable in the object path but I have no idea what else to do.

To see the JS code (lines 29-32):
https://github.com/olmansju/chineseCharacterHelpr/blob/master/JS/scripts.js

This Chinese widget isn't mine and I think I need to explore what is generating the list items for Chinese Characters in ul.options as that is probably extracting it for me somewhere and maybe I can just call that, I don't know.

On a site note, using keyup as a trigger seems to not always hit depending on how fast I type the character. I want to use the jquery trigger "change" on the same element I am copying so I tried:

```
$("#chinese-ime .typing").change(function (){
  alert("Did this trigger?");
})
```

I see the contents of .typing changing but the alert isn't triggering. Am I doing something wrong?

Thank you for your time! I understand this is long so I appreciate it!

Comment: You've put in effort to describe what your code *looks like* and to tell us that you "get a vague error"... But you haven't shown us an *actual example* of the code you're using or the *actual error*.  Those would be helpful.

Comment: I did, it just didn't stand out. I typed:
To see the JS code (lines 29-32): https://github.com/olmansju/chineseCharacterHelpr/blob/master/JS/scripts.js

Comment: Also here is the error: 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'choices' of undefined
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (scripts.js:32)

Comment: After a closer look at the error, I bet the problem is it is looking for currentPinyin.choices instead of just grabbing the text for currentPinyin  and putting the text for currentPinyin in $.wordDatabase.words.currentPinyin.choices; The question is how do I tell it that I want the text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A coworker figured it out for me, the issue was it was looking for choices inside of currentPinyin, not choices inside of the text for current pinyin.

So the correct output was this $.wordDatabase.words[currentPinyin].choices;